# Vuetify Deselecting v-tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to deselect the v-tabs component through code but it always ends up selecting the first tab.

When the v-model is set to -1 it's deselected on init but once any tab has been selected there seems to be no way to deselect. Any other value than one of the tabs will just select the first tab and set the index to 0. (v-model and value have the same result)

Here is a CodePen example:
https://codepen.io/arno-van-oordt/pen/qBBbmzY

- The index starts at -1
- Click tab 2 or 3 on either of the tab bars
- Click "Deselect"

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    tabIndex: {{tabIndex}}
    <v-tabs :value="tabIndex">
      <v-tab>Item One</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Item Two</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Item Three</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <v-tabs v-model="tabIndex">
      <v-tab>Item One</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Item Two</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Item Three</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <v-btn @click="deselect">Deselect</v-btn>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

  data: {
    tabIndex: -1
  },
  methods: {
    deselect: function() {
      this.tabIndex = -1;
    }
  }
});
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First tab is autoselected. 
A workaround :
Add fake first tab with `<v-tab class="pa-0 ma-0" style="min-width:0px" />` and a first empty tab item `<v-tab-item />`

Comment: Thanks! Just <v-tab class="pa-0" style="min-width:0px" /> seems to do the trick in my case.
To bad the v-tabs has no normal method of deselecting all.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that for the `v-tabs` component, the first tab (with index 0) is selected by default. With the version of Vuetify I'm using currently (2.2.22), I could not reproduce the initial state you described with the v-model set as -1, it still selected the first tab.

To solve your problem, you can use the `optional` prop defined for `<v-tabs>`, which does not require an active tab. When no tab is selected, the `v-model` is `undefined`:

```
<v-tabs
  optional
  ...
>
  ...
</v-tabs>
```

Comment: This solution has a side effect that might be pretty annoying: if you click 2 times on the same tab it will deselect the tab and not select anything. This clearly make a bad user experience because nothing really happen.

Comment: Well, the OP asked about a way to deselect the tab and this is one solution, although yes, this approach makes user deselection possible as well which is perhaps not wanted. A workaround would be to detect a user selection and avoid this behavior in that case, if that is what you want.